# Murderer as Food Judge

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story in which an alien murderer (cannibal?) is sentenced to be a food judge due his highly sensitive sensory capabilities.

Comment: I recall a short story of an alien food judge, having to choose between two human females, at a pie contest. Will go research title and author....

Comment: Do you remember when you read this? What language was it in?

Comment: yeah, that was it. It was a long time ago, in English. The choice he made was due to the boyfriends comment that she was good enough to eat.

Comment: I thought it might be in an Asimov or Clarke collection, but haven't found it yet. And I do know it was in a collection of short stories.

Comment: ...I couldn't find it when I researched, glad someone knew, and posted the correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["The Model of a Judge"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41147), a short story by [William Morrison](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1246) (pseudonym of [Joseph Samachson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Samachson)), available at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/32431). Any of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?41147) look familiar?

**The judge is an alien carnivore who has been converted into an imitation of a human:**

> Ronar thought back to the time when he had wandered over the surface of this, his native satellite. He no longer had the old desires, the old appetites. Only the faintest of ghosts still persisted, ghosts with no power to do harm. But he could remember the old feeling of pleasure, the delight of sinking his teeth into an animal he had brought down himself, the savage joy of gulping the tasty flesh. He didn't eat raw meat any more; he didn't eat meat at all. He had been conditioned against it. He was now half vegetarian, half synthetarian. His meals were nourishing, healthful, and a part of his life he would rather not think about.
>
> He took no real pleasure in the tasting of the cakes and other delicacies that born human beings favored. His sense of taste had remained keen only to the advantage of others. To himself it was a tantalizing mockery.

**All his senses are very keen:**

> He could hear every word. They had no idea how sharp his sense of hearing was, and he had no desire to disconcert them further by letting them know. He could hear every conversation taking place in ordinary tones in the large reception room. When he concentrated he could make out the whispers. At this point he had to concentrate, for Mrs. Claymore leaned over and breathed into her friend's attentive ear.

**He judges the cakes:**

> "But I don't think the judging is right. Mr. Ronar tastes hardly more than a crumb of each!"
>
> "A minimum of three crumbs," Ronar corrected her. "One from the body of the cake, one from the icing, and an additional crumb from each filling between layers."
>
> "But you can't judge a cake that way! You have to eat it, take a whole mouthful—"
>
> "Please, madam, permit me to explain. A crumb is all I need. I can analyze the contents of the cake sufficiently well from that. Let me take, for instance, cake Number 4, made from an excellent recipe, well baked. Martian granis flour, goover eggs, tingan-flavored salt, a trace of Venusian orange spice, synthetic shortening of the best quality. The icing is excellent, made with rare dipentose sugars which give it a delightful flavor. Unfortunately, however, the cake will not win first prize."
>
> An anguished cry rose from the audience. "Why?"
>
> "Through no fault of your own, dear lady. The purberries used in making the filling were not freshly picked. They have the characteristic flavor of refrigeration."

**Punch line mentioned in comments:**

> "Mmmmm." He kissed her shoulder. "You know, I didn't fall in love with you for your cooking, sweetheart. You don't have to bake any cakes for me. You're good enough to eat yourself."
>
> "He's right," thought Ronar, as he stared at her. "The man's right. Not in the way he means, but he's right." And suddenly, for one second of decision, Ronar's entire past seemed to flash through his mind.
>
> The young bride never knew why she won first prize.

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive rely. Both "best of" covers look familiar too; I know it wasn't that long ago (70/80's not 50's) that I read the story so its unlikely I actually saw it in a monthly.